# Can I get dependencies.child-chart.version from Helm template?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

I have this tree:

```
 environments
 ┣ staging
 ┃ ┣ Chart.yaml
 ┃ ┗ values.yaml
 services
 ┣ my-service
 ┃ ┣ helm
 ┃ ┃ ┣ templates
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ deployment.yaml
 ┃ ┃ ┣ Chart.yaml
 ┃ ┃ ┗ values.yaml
```

environments/staging/Chart.yaml look like this:

```
apiVersion: v2
name: staging
description: A Helm chart for Kubernetes
type: application
version: 0.1.0
appVersion: "1.0.0"
dependencies:
  - name: my-service
    repository: file://../../services/my-service/helm
    version: 79947968d75f9b728b321b070d12eaacd12636ca-SNAPSHOT
```

environments/staging/values.yaml look like this:

```
my-service:
  image:
    tag: 79947968d75f9b728b321b070d12eaacd12636ca-SNAPSHOT
```

services/my-service/helm/templates/deployment.yaml look like this:

```
...
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
        image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
...
```

There is a way to access to dependencies.my-service.version from my "child" deployment template, with something like this ?

```
        image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Chart.Dependencies.my-service.version }}"
```

If not (what I guess), do you please have tips to achieve this ?

Comment: there is nothing special you have to do. Subchart has its own values in yaml files, and you may overwrite those values on the parent chart. I highly recommend to you use "alias" and it will more understandable for you.